# Google vision api request format

Tags: node.js, api, google-vision

I'm pretty new to the google vision api and I am trying to make a `TEXT_DETECTION` request.

Currently I am reading from an image file, encoding it to `base64` and trying to pass it on to the request

```
const endPoint =`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${config.api_key}`;

fetch(endPoint, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    requests: [
      {
        image: {
          content: data
        },
        features: [
          {
            type: "TEXT_DETECTION"
          }
        ],
        imageContext: {
          langaugeHints: ["en"]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
})
```

But I am getting a `400` error. Could anyone spot the error in the code?.

Answer (score 1):

Found the typo at lan**gauge**Hints.